# How do I secure cookies in HAProxy 2.2+ using an `http-response` line?

Tags: haproxy

I'm upgrading from HAProxy 1.8 to 2.2 and the command `reqirep` has been deprecated and removed.  I used this previously to automatically add `Secure` to cookies that weren't previously secure.  I want to use the new `http-response` syntax.

My old code looks like this:

```
rspirep ^(set-cookie:\ (?:(?!(\ Secure|ASPXAUTH=)).)*)$ \1;\ Secure
```

This adds `; Secure` to any cookie header that doesn't contain  `Secure` or `ASPXAUTH=`.

I'd like to do the same thing with one of the modern `http-response` commands.

Here's my initial translation:

```
http-request replace-header Set-Cookie (.*) %[src];\ Secure if { hdr_reg(Set-Cookie) -i (?!(\ Secure|ASPXAUTH=)) }
#                           Replace the "Set-Cookie" header
#                                       That contains any value
#                                           With the initial value with "; Secure" appended to the end
#                                                           If the cookie doesn't contain " Secure" or "ASPXAUTH=", ignoring case
```

Is this the right approach?  Have you done this successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up with this as a solution.  It's not perfect because it will only look for `Secure` modifier on the end of the `Set-Cookie` line but it works for what we need.

```
  http-response replace-header Set-Cookie ^((?:.(?!\ [Ss]ecure))*)$ \1;\ Secure
```